# Escaping "=" (equal sign) in for /f

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, shell-script, escape-characters

I'm trying to run the following command in a "FOR /F" in Windows' shell...

`wmic process where ParentProcessId=%%PID%% get ProcessId`

The `=` between ParentProcessId and %PID% keeps gettings replace by a space.

The result being:

`for /F "usebackq" %b in (wmic process where ParentProcessId %PID% get ProcessId) do (`.

How would I escape this character = sign?

Comment: How do you mean it's 'getting replaced'? You type it in, and the equal sign magically turns into a space?  Are you using this in a batch file?

Comment: Put ' around it 
for /F "usebackq" %b in ('wmic process where ParentProcessId=%PID% get ProcessId')
...
Example : IN ('WMIC Path Win32_DiskPartition Where "BootPartition=true And PrimaryPartition=true" Get DeviceID /Format:list') DO

Comment: @Setekh That is wrong. `usebackq` requires backquotes `\`` not single quotes `'`

Comment: Nooo not userbackq ... ('WMIC...') get it

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
for /F "usebackq" %b in (`wmic process where ParentProcessId^=0 get ProcessId`) do echo %b
```

The “=” sign is escaped with a “^”. Also note that the `wmic` command itself is enclosed in “back quotes” as called for by your use of the `usebackq` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

#### How would I escape this character = sign?

```
for /F "usebackq" %%b in (wmic process where ParentProcessId=%PID% get ProcessId) do (
```

There are two problems with the above:

1. When using `"usebackq"` you need to put backquotes around the command to be processed by `for`.
2. There needs to be quotes `"` around the `where` clause of `wmic`.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set PID=1188
for /F "usebackq" %%b in (`wmic process where "ParentProcessId=%PID%" get ProcessId`) do (
  echo %%b
  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
ProcessId
2508
10100
ECHO is off.
```

Note:

- The `ECHO is off.` line is output because `wmic` outputs a final blank line.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: That's what i was trying to explain, but write it so messed up so i guess it's not understandable :D

Comment: Quoting didn't work for me but escaping the equal sign as per BillP3rd's answer did.